# How to save friendly urls in my browser history?

Tags: php

I use friendly urls in my site, But my browser does'nt save all urls in the history browser???

this is my .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule category/(.*)\.html index.php?inid=3&id=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule products/(.*)\.html index.php?inid=4&id=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're linking users to the `index.php?inid=3&id=###` URLs, that's what's going to show up in the browser history. Rewrite rules don't redirect the non-pretty URL to the pretty one, they just provide the pretty ones as alternates.

You'll need to change your site's links to go to the pretty versions.

As a side note, adding the `[QSA]` flag (query string attached) to the end of your rules will prevent the need to hard-code the QUERY_STRING variable into your rules.